# Can ActionScript Workers used to do database operation?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, actionscript

I am writing a very heavy application in AIR. I managed to overcome all Memory Leak issues. But the performance is degraded due to background DB operations (Sync).

My question is can I use ActionScript Workers do such background tasks?

Thanks,
Indrajit

Comment: Perceived performance would be drastically increased by asynchronous operations.

Comment: If you're using SQLLite and the built in AIR APIs; then you can already do those calls asynchronously using existing API.  If you're making remote calls ( HTTPService, WebService, or RemoteObject) those calls are already asynchronous.  I'm not sure what problems workers will solve for you.  ( CC @Jason Sturges )

Comment: Yes, that's true for remote calls. But if we asynchronous operation for local DB transaction. It anyway going to run in Single thread. Which is a performance lag.Remote calls are handled by Server and when returns they too causes performance lag.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. but one thing you need to be careful about is that you need to create instances of `File`, `SQLConnection`, `ByteArray` or anything else related to your database file, inside the Worker. creating them somewhere else and then passing them to the worker will trouble you.

if you are also looking for an easy way to use ActionScript workers, you may find this library helpful also. https://github.com/myflashlab/easyAS-Worker